# Set-Theory . What does $\min( |N_1(i)|, |N_1(j)| )$ mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, matrices, graph-theory

I'm getting deeper into graph-theory and I've been looking at different ways to visualize graphs using matrices along.  Of course there is an adjacency matrix (A) where the column (j) & row (i) labels are nodes; $A_{ij}$ is in {0,1} indicating if the nodes are connected.

**Topological Overlap Matrix**, TOM, is supposed to be a matrix transformation that gives the degree in which two nodes's 1st neighbors are connected.  It should push everything between 0 and 1.

**My main question**

1) What is $\min(k_i,k_j)$ ? Is this the minimum path between the two nodes?

**Other things I'm confused about:**

2) What is the $u$ is iterating over?

3) Why doesn't the set-theory version have the $u$ term?

The set-theory version makes much more sense to me but I'd like to be able to understand it both ways.

Here are 2 versions of the transformation from 2 different perspectives:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Your pictures look like power point: why not ask the presenter these questions directly?

Comment: It's from a YouTube video . I found a book talking about this and it makes a little more sense. https://books.google.com/books?id=fcFNCcCKjxQC&pg=PA12&lpg=PA12&dq=denominator+topological+overlap+matrix&source=bl&ots=AxvkD0YPVm&sig=G2XUFj5ms4JIT5JT-lTcR5ScVXU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjU2PG_z93LAhVG1CYKHXiBDIEQ6AEIVTAI#v=onepage&q=denominator%20topological%20overlap%20matrix&f=false

Comment: ok. Well, $\min(k_i, k_j)$ means you look at the numbers $k_i$ and $k_j$, decide which of them is smaller and pick that one. Examples: $\min(1,2) = 1$ and $\min(2,2) = 2$.

Comment: ! that makes sense.  I thought it had to do with a minimum path distance on the graph but that definitely sounds right.

Comment: @Moritz if you put the answer in I can accept it.  I figured out what was wrong in my function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought it was the minimum path between two nodes in the network but as stated by Mortiz above, it is basically just the minimum of those 2 values.  I thought it was much more complicated but it just normalized the value between 0 and 1.